# month name translation

Tags: date, translation

I use the birdtips theme and it formats the post date as

```
$birdtips_posted = date(__('Y. F j.', 'birdtips'),  strtotime(get_the_time("Y-m-d")));
```

where Y. F j. is already rewritten to reflect my language. As far as I understand, __ is the translation function, but how can I tell Wordpress that I use Hungarian, and will it translate month names automatically, or I should give the names in a .po file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`date_i18n()`](http://queryposts.com/function/date_i18n/):

```
date_i18n( 'Y. F j.',  strtotime( get_the_time( "Y-m-d" ) ) );
```

From the function’s description:

> Retrieve the date in localized format, based on timestamp.
>
> If the locale specifies the locale month and weekday, then the locale will
>   take over the format for the date. If it isn't, then the date format string
>   will be used instead.

A timestamp is a [UNIX timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php), a single number, for example 1366784091.

Comment: I would suggest a slight amendment: `date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ),  strtotime( get_the_time( "Y-m-d" ) ) );`

Comment: @vancoder This is correct when you don’t know the context. When you change code for a personal use case you don’t need the same format in all places.

Comment: Thanks it worked. What does 'based on timestamp' mean?

Comment: @GergelyBuday I made an update to my answer. :)

Comment: @toscho: well, I misunderstood the sentence, the date is based on the timestamp, but the localized format is based on the locale.