# translation does not work for 'Home'

Tags: themes, translation

Using the birdtips theme, translation of messages generally works, with some [minor omissions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96957/month-name-translation).

When I click on a page, a new line appears below the header image saying

```
Home >> MyPage
```

Now, "Home" is not translated to the language set in the locale, although the code invokes a translation function:

```
<?php _e('Home', 'birdtips'); ?>
```

The file `wp-content/languages/hu_HU.po` does contain the translation of this string:

```
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Kezdőlap"
```

Is this a bug in the theme? How can I fix this?

Comment: You are definitely looking at the correct code? That of the breadcrumb?

Comment: `wp-content/languages/hu_HU.po` is for WordPress, not for the theme.

Comment: @vancoder: the code is below `<ul id="pankuzu">`, and this is the id at the mentioned place.

Comment: That tells me nothing as I'm not familiar with the theme, and my Hungarian is a little rusty. Regardless, I believe @toscho has correctly identified your problem.

Comment: indeed, @toscho was right, I created a translation file for the theme and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Might be worth putting in as an answer Gergely.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.