# WordPress AJAX calls not detecting language properly?

Tags: ajax, localization

I have a WordPress multisite, which is in both english and french. On the french site, localization is working great (using `date_l18n()` for dates, and `__()`, etc. for the rest).

When an AJAX call sends off to WP and returns data (the same rendering functions being called from initial page load and AJAX), however, they are returning English date values.

**Example:** Date archive says "septembre 2013". You click the Next Month button, which sends off to AJAX and returns the new month header, and article listing. It's returning "October 2013" rather than "octobre 2013".

Is this a known bug, or should I be submitting this to track?

```
function render_event_archive_month_header( $date = null, $echo = true ) {
    $date_str = strtotime( $date );

    if( ! $echo )
        ob_start();

    <?php echo date_i18n('F Y', $date_str ); ?>

    <?php
    if( ! $echo ) {
        $data = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

This is being passed a yyyy-mm-dd date value, like so

```
render_event_archive_month_header( '2013-10' );
```

from within my Ajax action callback.

Comment: Depends on the code creating the response. Please add it to your question. Do you use [`date_i18n()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/96959/73)?

Comment: Yes I am. I simplified the code slightly. I removed next/previous links themselves (use /2013/10/ scheme as normal).

Comment: Same function being called when going to `domain.com/events` (results in current month), and same function called for AJAX.

Comment: What do you get when you let the AJAX function return `$GLOBALS['wp_locale']`?

Comment: It's returning the English values. My WP install was en_US, and I've installed the fr_FR .mo and .po files for site 2. This is on site 2. `WP_LANG` is not set in wp-config.php.

Comment: Hm, strange. Try `'en_US' === get_locale() or load_default_textdomain();` in your AJAX callback. If that doesn’t work, the language is not detected correctly.

Comment: @toscho "It's returning the English values" tells me that the user didn't actually dump what you asked for, but described his problem again.

Comment: @kaiser `$GLOBALS['wp_locale']` is an object holding the translated values.

Comment: @toscho Yeah, you know that I know that. :) But the comment from the OP tells me that he didn't dump it, but just repeated his question/problem.

Comment: @EricHolmes No need to get rude. Instead read my comment again. I _assumed_ that, so it hasn't been clear to me. Anyway. Please don't add debug info into comments. Edit your post instead. Later readers might skip comments and not get an important part of the process.

Comment: @kaiser sorry, it's been a long morning. Going to mark this as off-topic. Solution described below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it relates to a plugin's functionality (WP Native Dashboard), and not WordPress core itself.

Comment: @EricHolmes No bad feelings or other emotions involved over here. Glad you found the problem.

Comment: @EricHolmes This affects all situations where front end and back language is different. There are many plugins doing that, so I think it is worth keeping this here.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for all the help Toscho! The issue was actually quite obvious after a night of sleep. I am using WP Native Dashboard. In case you don't know what that is, it allows you to change the language of the Admin section of the site.

Considering WP Ajax is considered to be admin, it's changing the language like so. Once I logged out, or changed the back end language to FR, it's working as intended.

I'll report this to the plugin author as a bug.

Comment: This isn’t really a bug. There is no safe way to know in admin-ajax if a function was called from front end or back end. But it is good to see you figured it out.

Comment: does admin-ajax receive a referrer or origin? If so, perhaps a simple URL check for `wp-admin` would do the trick for any of these plugins. :)

Comment: Plugins don’t _have to_ send a referer value with their requests.